# Hive: how to move a database and recreate tables to minimize downtime?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

The ingestion of a Hive database is very slow. To reduce the ingestion time, I'm ingesting it to a temp database, then I do  `hdfs dfs -rmdir /path/to/original_db` and a `hdfs dfs -mv /path/of/temp_db /path/to/original_db`. Now I need to recreate the tables.

I plan to do a `DROP DATABASE temp_db CASCADE` and recreate the new tables created by spark and change the command generated by `SHOW CREATE TABLE temp_db.one_table`. I'll need to do it of each table and replace the temp_db location with the new original location.

Is there a better way to do it? Maybe I can just rename the DB and set a new location for the tables.

Comment: is the new database on the same metastore as the current one? And, is this a one-time task or are you trying to build a repeatable data ingestion process?

Comment: The database is in the same metastore. It must be repeatable, like importing to a temp database, deleting the old one and renaming the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer here, so here is my solution.

The solution I designed above worked fine. Using it, even my queries that started during the data update are working fine. Yarn takes care of any problem.

Here is the commands that I used when importing a new version of `/path/mydb`. I'm using external Hive tables

1. Import new data to `mydb_landing`. The tables are created using this pyspark command: `df.write.option("path", table_data_path).format("orc").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(".".join(['mydb_landing', table_name]))`
2. I already have all table names, so I get all create statments:

```
        create_stmts = [
            spark.sql(
                'show create table {schema}.{table_name}'.format(schema=base_dest_landing, table_name=table_name)
                ).first().createtab_stmt 
            for table_name in tables
            ]
```

3. Drop target database in Hive: `spark.sql('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {} CASCADE'.format(base_dest))`
4. Since it has just external tables, I now delete the data from hdfs: `hdfs dfs -rm -r -f -skipTrash "/path/mydb"`
5. Move from `mydb_landing` to `mydb`. It is a very quick operation, basically a rename: `hdfs dfs -mv '/path/mydb_landing' '/path/mydb``
6. Now I must recreate the database and tables pointing to the "new" location: `CREATE DATABASE mydb LOCATION '/path/mydb'`
7. Recreate tables. This guarantees that I get any schema update:

```
   for stmt in create_stmts:
           create_stmt = stmt.replace('_landing', '')
           spark.sql(create_stmt)
```

8. Delete landing database from Hive: `spark.sql('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb_landing CASCADE)`

This [Impala blog post](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-ingest-and-query-fast-data-with-impala-without-kudu/) has some nice ideas using Hive views.